# Can't connect to azure iot hub through local ionic app

Tags: angular, azure, ionic-framework, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to connect my ionic 4 app ( angular 7 ) with azure iot hub.I am trying to send msgs from my app to iot hub. Downloaded "azure-iothub" inside my ionic project and trying to import "client" to form connection but while building getting errors .

Tried setting these specific modules false for browser , it builds with warnings but app doesn't load on localhost.
Also tried http post  request but there also getting CORS error as " localhost is not allowed to access ".

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import {Client} from 'azure-iothub';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
    var connectionString = '**********';

    var client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString);

    client.open(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Could not connect: ' + err.message);
      } else {
        console.log('Service client connected');
    }});

  }
}
```

Getting the following error-
[error while building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTfk6.png)

Comment: any other way with which i can use azure iot hub to connect to my ionic app ????????

Answer (score 0):

The Azure IoT Node SDK is not supported for use within a browser.

Comment: any other way with which i can use azure iot hub to connect to my ionic app ????????